# Why does not execute printf inside function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, gcc

Following code compile and run on GCC compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int arr[10];

 int func()
 {
      printf("In func\n");
      return 0;
 }

int main() 
{
    if (&arr[func()])
        printf("In main\n");
     return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
In main
```

Why does not execute `printf("In func\n");` ?

Comment: What does this line of code do `if (&arr[func()])`? When will the address of any element of `arr` be zero? Are you sure you have no DOS control characters in your code? Getting any compiler warnings? What?

Comment: Compile your code with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). You should observe the `printf`.

Comment: Or at least make sure you have 'saved' since you posted the code, then compile with warnings enabled and proceed.

Comment: I just pasted your code and got `In func/In main`. (gcc 5.4.0)

Comment: Even a really clever optimizer can only learn that the check is always non-zero, so it has to generate the side-effect.

Comment: I compiled and ren your code, it does run and both prints are printed as expected. what is the point of the `if` statment it is always valued to true since `&arr[func()]` is the address of the `arr[0]`. what compiler are you using?

Comment: Let's make a small change to prevent gcc from optimizing `func()` away... `int *p = &arr[func()]; if (p) printf("In main\n");` and try again.

Comment: @Jayesh: I guess you just did not compile correctly your program. Please give the actual compilation command that you typed in a terminal

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch this is indeed a gcc issue. With gcc 7.3, `func()` is optimized out of `main()` completely. Even though it produces output. Earlier versions of gcc handle it fine. Really strange. `.string "In func"` is stored, the `func()` function is there, but it is completely omitted from the code generation for `main:` So @Jayesh ain't crazy.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: When compiling with `gcc -Wall -g jayesh.c -o jayesh` I do observe the two outputs, with gcc 7.3 on Debian/Sid. And even with  `gcc -O -Wall -g jayesh.c -o jayesh` I also observe the output. And even with `-O3`; if that was not the case it would be a serious optimization bug. So we cannot reproduce your observation.

Comment: I compiled with the latest 4.15.8 kernel with gcc `7.3.0` and it's gone. This is bizarre. I'll post the assembly.

Comment: Please state whether you are aware of the content of the link provided by @PkmX in their answer. The similarity of the code examples is striking. If you are trying to test StackOverflowers, I vote to applaude PkmX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a subtle issue, either intended, or unintended with various combinations of the latest gcc. ver 7.3 on the latest kernel 4.15.8 on Archlinux. For whatever reason the call to `func()` is omitted for the code generated for `main()`. e.g.

```
$ gcc -S -masm=intel -o infunc2.asm infunc2.c
```

The generated assembly is:

```
$ cat infunc2.asm
        .file   "infunc2.c"
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        .text
        .comm   arr,40,32
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "In func"
        .text
        .globl  func
        .type   func, @function
func:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        push    rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        mov     rbp, rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        lea     rdi, .LC0[rip]
        call    puts@PLT
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   func, .-func
        .section        .rodata
.LC1:
        .string "In main"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc
        push    rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        mov     rbp, rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        lea     rdi, .LC1[rip]
        call    puts@PLT
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 7.3.0"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Note the call to `func()` is labeled `.LFB0:` above. The procedure for `main:` does not call `func` or `.LFB0:` at all, despite it being present, and despite the `"In func"` string being present in `.LC0:`. I suspect this is not intended behavior.

For example, simple compilation without optimization `-O0` the function is not called, e.g.:

```
$ gcc -g -O0 -o bin/if2 infunc2.c
$ ./bin/if2
In main
```

Changing the code to store the address of `arr[func()]` does force `func()` to be called, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[10];

int func()
{
    printf ("In func\n");
    return 0;
}

int main (void)
{
    int *p = &arr[func()];
    if (p)
        printf("In main\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o bin/infunc infunc.c
$ ./bin/infunc
In func
In main
```

And the generated assembly supports the different behavior:

```
$ gcc -S -masm=intel -o infunc.asm infunc.c

$ cat infunc.asm
        .file   "infunc.c"
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        .text
        .comm   arr,40,32
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "In func"
        .text
        .globl  func
        .type   func, @function
func:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        push    rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        mov     rbp, rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        lea     rdi, .LC0[rip]
        call    puts@PLT
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   func, .-func
        .section        .rodata
.LC1:
        .string "In main"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc
        push    rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        mov     rbp, rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     eax, 0
        call    func
        cdqe
        lea     rdx, 0[0+rax*4]
        lea     rax, arr[rip]
        add     rax, rdx
        mov     QWORD PTR -8[rbp], rax
        cmp     QWORD PTR -8[rbp], 0
        je      .L4
        lea     rdi, .LC1[rip]
        call    puts@PLT
.L4:
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 7.3.0"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I wish I could provide some logical explanation for the handling here, but I can only document it. Seems we need to talk with the guys on the gcc list.

---

**Side effects discarded in address computation inside 'if'**

This seems to be a regression in gcc that will appear depending on whether an individual distro applies enough patching to mask it. It is a gcc bug in work. [Bug 84607](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84607)

Comment: You should report a bug on your Linux distribution. BTW, On Debian/Sid I don't observe that.

Comment: That could also explain some recent unexplained issue with the distro `:(`. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Maybe your distro has some strange spec file which forces some optimization

Comment: I think this is just a pure regression somewhere in the gcc line of things on Arch. There are a couple of unexplained errors on the Arch list today (one mine), whatever is causing this seems like a perfect candidate for the problems. "Houston -- we have a problem..."

Answer (score 2):

This is a gcc bug ([#84607](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84607)) and has been fixed in gcc 7.3.1 or later.

Comment: This seems to be the source of the basic idea of the code quote in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your compilation. I use gcc to compile. I compiled your file like this:

```
gcc main.c -o prog
./prog
In func
In main
```

Seems good to me. Check the procedure on how to compile with you compiler if you use a different compiler than gcc. Also I use gcc 7.3

Comment: And with GCC 7.3 the same output happens with `-O`, `-O2`, `-O3`.

Comment: GCC 7.3.0 on a Mac shows the bug for me (both this version and the one from GCC Bug #84607 — with `-O0`, `-O1`, `-O2` or `-O3`.